# Masonry item overflows into the next column

Tags: html, css, masonry, css-multicolumn-layout

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="masonry-container">
    <div class="masonry-item">
        <!-- post thumbnail -->
        <a href="#">
            <img src="">
        </a>
        <!-- /post thumbnail -->
        <div class="masonry-body">
            <h3><a href="#" title="">Title</a></h3>

            Some text...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`.masonry-container` has no height specified whatsoever, but what happens is after some random height the last item overflows into the next column resulting in items to appear broken in the grid.

My CSS:

```
.masonry-container {
    width: 100%;
    columns: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
    .masonry-item {
        margin: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: auto;
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        .masonry-body {
            padding: 30px;
            max-width: 100%;
            h3 {
                font-family: 'Playfair Display';
                font-weight: 700;
                font-size: 1.6em;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pgk2.png)

Comment: This is not HTML, it's PHP (probably from WordPress), Please give the generated HTML code.

Comment: @yunzen There...

Comment: I don't see any issue here. Your screenshot doesn't show anything wrong. You need to provide for a [mcve]

Comment: @yunzen My screenshot doesn't show anything wrong? Look again...

Comment: You have to hint us. What is apparent to you must not be recognised by others

Comment: @yunzen I said in the title it overflows into another column.

Comment: Not in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pgk2.png

Comment: Also this is not CSS-Grid....